# Resize html components

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to html and I have problem with resizing components in my html page. I want to for example menu in navbar be in same line in different resolutions. Because now in my code, when I change resolution, menu is in two lines. Menu has only this 4 categories(Study, Harmonogram, FAQ, Erasmus) so one category is 25% of navbar. 
 See pics:
[1920x1080 resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Doe0d.png)
,[smaller resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHwtX.png)

html:

```
<div class="navbar">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Study
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Text1</a>
                    <a href="#">Text2</a>
                    <a href="#">Text3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Harmonogram 
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">FAQ 
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Text1</a>
                    <a href="#">Text2</a>
                    <a href="#">Text3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Erasmus 
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

style.css

```
body{
  background: white;
}

h2 {
  color: #3399ff;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 150px;
}

/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 21vh;
  background-color: inherit;
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to remove the padding
second, you have to set width with %, so when the resolution changes the width changes too.

```css
body{
  background: white;
}

h2 {
  color: #3399ff;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 150px;
}

/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:25%;
  height:30px;
  line-hight:30px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  /*padding: 14px 21vh;*/
  background-color: inherit;
    height:30px;
  line-hight:30px;
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
 width:100%;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content{
width:25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Study
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Text1</a>
                    <a href="#">Text2</a>
                    <a href="#">Text3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Harmonogram 
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">FAQ 
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Text1</a>
                    <a href="#">Text2</a>
                    <a href="#">Text3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Erasmus 
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.header {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            margin-left:20px;
        }

        .boxA {
            float: left;
            width:30%;
            text-align:center;
            border:1px solid;
            height:auto;
            padding-top:25px;
            margin-left:20px;
        }

        p {
            width: 100%;
           text-align:left;
        }

        img {
            width: 90%;
            height: 200px;
        }
        .text {
        width:90%;
        display:inline-block;

        }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="header">News</div>
    <div class="boxA">
        <img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" alt="Mountain View" width="500" height="377">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut illum laboriosam voluptatem ullam id. Rerum ratione repellendus minus, doloribus earum quos, </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxA">
        <img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" alt="Mountain View" width="500" height="377">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut illum laboriosam voluptatem ullam id. Rerum ratione repellendus minus, doloribus earum quos,</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to edit dropdown content? Because now is not in right position.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Look at picture: https://i.imgur.com/SGmqKsC.png , dropdown content is too far from Menu category. How to set that content in the middle of the category?

Comment: try adding to the css - see my example now, i update it

.dropdown-content{
width:25%;
}

Comment: One more question, if you look at your snippet, around every category is gray background, how to set it 25% width and another color?

Comment: try it now :)    i fixed it

Comment: /* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
 width:100%;
}

Comment: I'm trying all day do something like that: https://i.imgur.com/brtxH3g.png
It is box with image and short text below image (after click on left or right button it will show new articles) but I don't know how to write style.css

Comment: take a look at the second snippet that i added

Comment: I have something similar, but I don't know how to set these boxes in the middle of page

Comment: use margin: 0 auto; in the wraps div

Comment: Can you pls add me on discord: Royalko#9573. I don't want to spam here.

Comment: sorry i dont have :(

Comment: so what are you using? I will add you

Answer (score 0):

add `width: 25%;` to `.dropdown` css. For responsiveness, using media queries will be a better option.

```
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 25%;
}
```